# REGEX How to get start time of youtube URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I have the following regex that I'm using in Javascript:

```
/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

It gets me the video ID correctly. I want to expand it to extract start time of videos:

I know there are at least two formats (if not more): "t="  and  "start="

http://youtu.be/xxxxxxxx?**t=30s**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx**&start=30**

thanks,

Comment: I had seen that post already when I was searching. I didn't want all that extra code when I'm already using regex to retrieve video id. I wanted to be able to expand the current regex. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^.*?(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)(?:(\?t|&start)=(\d+))?.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN7bO0/1)

Comment: Thanks, it works!! "t" can be either "?t" or "&t", so I added the OR to your answer, here is what I ended up with:

^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)(?:(\?t|\&t|&start)=(\d+))?.*

and can satisfy all these:

    http://youtu.be/xxxxxxxx?t=30s

    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx&start=30

    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx&t=70

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for `javascript`

```
   var re = /(t=|start=)(?:\d+)/g;
    var str = 'http://youtu.be/xxxxxxxx?t=30s\n\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx&start=30';
    var m;

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    alert(eg m[0])
    }
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/oW2hV4/1)